# Can multiple Cubits listen to the same state file in Flutter Cubit?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, cubit

I am working on a complex Flutter application using the Cubit state management library. I have multiple Cubits in my application, and I'm wondering if it is possible for them to listen to the same state file. Essentially, I want to share a single state file across multiple Cubits.

To avoid redoing everything if my approach failed, I haven't attempted any specific implementation yet. However, I want to explore the possibility of having multiple Cubits subscribe to the same state file, as it would simplify my application structure and reduce code duplication.

Comment: what about inherited state class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define a state class to pass it to your app

```
void main() {
 YourState instance = YourState();
 runApp(RootApp(state: instance));
}
```

Passing the state class to your cubit:

```
class RootApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootApp({super.key, required this.state});
  final YourState state;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider<ExampleCubit>(
          create: (context) => ExampleCubit(state)),
      BlocProvider<ExampleTwoCubit>(
          create: (context) => ExampleTwoCubit(state)),
```